# Print the filter data by data and interviewer in table using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating interview form using `reactjs`, in which I am using the route to accessing different links. I am using `firebase` for storing the data.

[image]

```js
 class Contact extends React.Component {
          constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
              arr: [],
              records:[],
              Address:'',
              printabledata:[],
              singledata:{},
              date:'',
              iround:''

            };
            self = this;
              this.printAllRecord = this.printAllRecord.bind(this);
              this.filterByInterviewer = this.filterByInterviewer.bind(this);
              this.filterByDate = this.filterByDate.bind(this);
              this.handleChangedate = this.handleChangedate.bind(this);
              this.handleChangeiround = this.handleChangeiround.bind(this);
                      }
                       handleChangedate(event) {
                          this.setState({date: event.target.value.toUpperCase()});
                        }
                         handleChangeiround(event) {
                          this.setState({iround: event.target.value});
                        }


          componentWillMount() {  
          var formdata2 = firebase.database().ref("vishal-aaede/");
            formdata2.on("value", function (snap) {
                data = snap.val();
                self.setState({arr: data});
            });
          }

          componentDidUpdate(){
            var data=this.state.arr,
              headerArray=[];
              for (var key in data){
                headerArray.push(key);
              }console.log(headerArray);


           headerArray.forEach(function(val){
            self.printAllRecord(data[val]);
            self.state.records.push(data[val]);
              console.log(data[val].Address);
           });
           self.state.singledata=data[headerArray[0]];       
          }
          printAllRecord(param,index) {         
            self.state.printabledata.push(<tr>
              <td>{param.Name}</td>
              <td>{param.Round}</td>
              <td>{param.Email}</td>
              <td>{param.Date}</td>
              <td>{param.Phone}</td>
              <td>{param.Address}</td>
              <td>{param.Gender}</td>
              <td>{param.Fresh}</td>
              <td>{param.time}</td>
            </tr>);     
          }
        filterByInterviewer(){
           self.state.records.forEach(function(val){
           if(val.Round==self.state.iround){
             self.printAllRecord(val);
             console.log(val.Round+" - "+val.Name);
           }
         });
        }
        filterByDate(){
         self.state.records.forEach(function(val){
           if(val.Date==self.state.date){
             self.printAllRecord(val);
             console.log(val.Date+" - "+val.Name);
           }
         });
        }
           render() {
               return (
                 <div>
                   <h2>Candidate RECORD !!!!</h2>
                   <div>
                      <div>
                        <div className = "container">
                          <form classNameName = "form-horizontal" name = "record_form" id = "record_form">            
                            <div className = "form-group row">
                              <label className = "control-label col-lg-4" htmlFor = "filterdatetxt">Date:</label>
                              <div className = "col-lg-5">
                              <input type = "date" className = "form-control" ref = "filterdatetxt" name = "filterdatetxt" id = "filterdatetxt" placeholder = "Enter Date" onChange={this.handleChangedate} />
                              </div>
                             <div className = "col-lg-3">
                              <button name = "filter_date_btn" id = "filter_date_btn" type = "button" className = "btn btn-danger" onClick={this.filterByDate}>Filter By Date</button>
                             </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className = "form-group row">
                              <label className = "control-label col-lg-4" htmlFor = "interview_round">Feedback By Interviewer:</label>
                              <div className = "col-lg-5">
                              <select className = "form-control" ref = "interview_round" onChange={this.handleChangeiround} id = "interview_round" name = "interview_round"  >
                                <option value = "1">Select Round</option>
                                     <option value = "HR">HR</option>
                                     <option value = "TR">Technical Round</option>
                                     <option value = "FR">Final Round</option>
                              </select>
                              </div>
                            <div className = "col-lg-3">
                              <button name = "filter_date_btn" id = "filter_date_btn" type = "button" className = "btn btn-danger"  onClick={this.filterByInterviewer} >Filter By Interviewer</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className = "row">
                            <div className = "col-lg-3"></div>
                            <div className = "col-lg-3">

                            </div>
                            <div className = "col-lg-3">
                            <Link to="/contact">
                              <button name = "view_all_btn" id = "view_all_btn" type = "button" className = "btn btn-danger"  >View All Record</button>
                              </Link>
                            </div>
                            <div className = "col-lg-3">
                               <IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">
                              <button name = "back_btn" id = "back_btn" type = "button" className = "btn btn-danger" >Go Back</button>
                              </IndexLink>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                          </form>
                          <div className="blank_div"></div>
                        </div>        
                      </div>
                      <div className="row"> 

                        <div className="col-sm-12">
                          <div className = "container-fluid table-responsive">            
                            <table className = "table table-bordered">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                 <th>Name</th>
                                 <th>Interview Round</th>
                                 <th>Email</th>
                                 <th>Date</th>
                                 <th>Phone Number</th>
                                 <th>Address</th>
                                 <th>Gender</th>  
                                 <th>Experience</th>
                                 <th>Time</th>
                               </tr>
                              </thead>
                             <tbody>
                              {this.state.printabledata}
                             </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
               )
             }
            }
```

Here is the image in which you can see the users data. When users fill the interview form and submit the data that data go to firebase I fetch that data in the table.

So here 2 filter buttons. The main issue is that when I click on the date that time data filter and print all data on that date. Same for interviewer round.

I do all thing and all filter data are so on console but I want it to on my table

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't printAllRecord update the state? I think you are doing everything correct but filtering data you are not updating state,. You are updating a state object but which will never call render method unless you call a method setState.

```
printAllRecord(param,index) {    
        let printabledata = self.state.printabledata ? self.state.printabledata : [];
        printabledata.push(<tr>
          <td>{param.Name}</td>
          <td>{param.Round}</td>
          <td>{param.Email}</td>
          <td>{param.Date}</td>
          <td>{param.Phone}</td>
          <td>{param.Address}</td>
          <td>{param.Gender}</td>
          <td>{param.Fresh}</td>
          <td>{param.time}</td>
        </tr>);     
      }

      self.setState({printabledata:printabledata});
}
```

Comment: thank you, but actually i got one error in console  Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token (149:10)
  147 |         }
  148 | 
> 149 |       self.setState({printabledata:printabledata});
      |           ^
  150 | } what should i do to remove it ? Can you plz update my code its very helpful.if you do

Comment: please help me. i cannot understand where should i put this data.

Comment: Can you remove curly brace above setState call

Comment: infinite loop running after removing braces.. @Akash Bhandwalkar

Comment: You should be setting the state just before the end of filterByDate() function. The one above tries to set state on each iteration of the loop.